# In createjs textAlign Center Causing hit area misalignment

Tags: text, createjs

When I set up text as a link, set a bounds shape, and set the hit area to the bounds shape, my hit area is off if the textAlign = 'center'.  Any ideas?

```
var linkColor = "#0000ff";
var linkFont = "bold 14px Times";

var presentationLink = new createjs.Text("View Presentation", linkFont, linkColor);
presentationLink.textAlign = "left";
presentationLink.maxWidth = 170;
presentationLink.x = 300;
presentationLink.y = 125;
stage.addChild(presentationLink);
```

var plBounds = presentationLink.getTransformedBounds();

```
var s = new createjs.Shape().set({ x: plBounds.x, y: plBounds.y + plBounds.height });
s.graphics.s(linkColor).moveTo(0, 0).lineTo(plBounds.width, 0);
stage.addChild(s);

var hitAreaForPLink = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#ffffff").drawRect(-10, -10, plBounds.width + 20, plBounds.height + 10));
presentationLink.hitArea = hitAreaForPLink;

stage.enableMouseOver();

presentationLink.on("mouseover", function () {
    presentationLink.cursor = "pointer";
});
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to set the cursor on mouseover. That's specifically what `cursor` does (set a cursor that will be applied on mouseover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hitArea` is positioned according to its owner's coordinate system. That is, all of the owner's transformations are applied to the `hitArea`. This is so that if you were to animate the owner, the `hitArea` would track it as expected.

Since the transformation is already applied, you need to use `getBounds`, not `getTransformedBounds`. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gskinner/uagv5t84/2/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  I'm still pretty new at using HTML5 Canvas and the createJS suite.  If you're THE creator of createjs, thanks for all your work.  It is an extremely useful tool!

Comment: @gskinner, I am facing the same problem. Just one difference is we allow user to change the alignment after adding the text. Could you please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314986/createjs-text-alignment-changed-but-not-the-hit-area